# how to get linux file modification history including who:group

Tags: linux

I want to trace the modification history of a specific file. Does linux have commands allow me to get some details like who, when, did what(access, write, execute).

eg.

```
bob:adm read $timestamp 
alice:user write $timestamp
```

I know stat can do some of it, but can it also show me who/group modified the file?

Comment: Those data aren't tracked on the default file systems of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most File Systems simply don't track those data.

[Journaling file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_file_system) track them (at least the write operations) but usually just the last ones.

Without a very specific file system, you won't have those data.

Comment: `ext2` (not journaling) also stores timestamps for last modification. Journaling is really about maintaining a log of uncommitted transactions so you can recover from crashes or power failures.

Comment: All filesystems I know store the last modification time. But not journaling FS store only the last one.

Comment: I did not understand your comment. Could you reword/explain?

Comment: I mean that storing the last modification time isn't a specificity of ext2 : all file systems do it. But the need of OP is much more important (who reads, for example).

Comment: Yes. I agree with that. What I was trying to say, by giving a counter example of 'ext2' is: Logging access timestamps has nothing to do with Journaling. And that therefore, you might want to reword your answer, because currently it sounds like that is what Journaling is all about.